# Inherited class property injection with autofac

Tags: c#, .net-core, autofac

I hope to register with autofac property injection,But can't work ClassA property = null.Not injected successfully,how to change my code

```
public interface IRepository
{
}

public class Repository : IRepository
{
    public Repository()
    {

    }

}
```

this my base class

```
public class RepositoryBase : Repository
{
    public ClassA ClassA { get; set; }
    public RepositoryBase()
    {
            
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        ClassA.Exec();
    }
}
```

//Does property injection need to inject ClassA?

```
public class ClassA
    {
        public ClassA()
        {

        }

        public void Exec()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test");
        }
    }
```

call method

```
public interface ITestRepository
{
    void ExecPrint();
}

public class TestRepository : RepositoryBase, ITestRepository
{
    public TestRepository()
    {

    }

    public void ExecPrint()
    {
        Print();
    }
}
```

this my autofac register code

```
public class ContainerModule : Module
        {
            protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
            {
                var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
                    .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
                    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                    .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
                    ;
    
                builder.RegisterType<ClassA>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<RepositoryBase>().InstancePerLifetimeScope().PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies);
            }
        }
```

[call Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1fus.png)

RepositoryBase ClassA property = nulll

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. Your code doesn't compile.

Comment: @mjwills I modified my code

Comment: Where is your registration for `ClassA`?

Comment: Does property injection need to inject ClassA?

Comment: It defintely needs ClassA to be registered.

Comment: builder.RegisterType<ClassA>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<RepositoryBase>().InstancePerLifetimeScope().PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies); Can't work

Comment: `Does property injection need to inject ClassA?` You tell us. You seem to be complaining it is `null`, so I am _assuming_ you want it injected.

Comment: When _specifically_ is `ClassA` null? Why are you using property injection rather than constructor injection?

Comment: `TestRepository` needs `PropertiesAutowired` too.

Comment: Maybe not the main focus here, but naming your derived class `Base` is a confusing thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying PropertiesAutowired for the base class, but not for the main types.

So changing your registration to :

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
            .PropertiesAutowired()
            ;

builder.RegisterType<ClassA>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Will make sure that the final implementations do receive the property.

Also since I guess you would resolve by :

```
var container = builder.Build();
var test = container.Resolve<ITestRepository>();
test.ExecPrint();
```

You do not need to register RepositoryBase, autofac does not require the full class hierarchy to be registered, only the final type you use.